# Reverse proxy on 127.0.0.1 works locally, but not over the network

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

Two web servers, bound to 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8081. Curl validates they work as expected.

Apache with the following hosts:

```
Host 192.168.1.1:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
  ProxyPass             /       http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse      /       http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ServerName 192.168.1.1
  ServerAlias http://192.168.1.1
</VirtualHost>

Host 192.168.1.2:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
  ProxyPass             /       http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse      /       http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ServerName 192.168.1.2
  ServerAlias http://192.168.1.2
</VirtualHost>
```

On the server I can curl to the hosts and receive appropriate response.  (curl 192.168.1.1 gives me the web server response from  localhost:8080)

Remote hosts cannot connect to 192.168.1.1 or .2 at all.  What am I missing?

**Re: comments**

Yes, the default directory Directive is still in place.

```
# Deny access to root file system
<Directory />
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        deny from all
</Directory>
```

No apache logs are generated when trying to reach 192.168.1.1 remotely.  They are generated when curl from local.

If I bind the webservers to *:8080 and *:8081 instead of binding to localhost, I can access them from a remote host via 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2.

**Edit 2:**

curl verbose output:  (similar for second webserver, and for 127.0.0.1:portnum)

```
[user@host mingle_12_2_1]$ curl -v 192.168.1.1
* About to connect() to 192.168.1.1 port 80
*   Trying 192.168.1.1... connected
* Connected to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: 192.168.1.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 16:22:08 GMT
< Server: Jetty(6.1.19)
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Location: http://192.168.1.1/install
< X-Runtime: 130
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 94
< Connection: close
Closing connection #0
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://192.168.1.1/install">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

log from the request local

```
192.168.1.1 - - [16/Oct/2012:12:22:08 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 94
```

no apache access log or error log generated when requests from remote clients.

**Edit 3**

curl and logs to both hosts are  identical, except for the IP address used.  Working w/ security admins to get the locked down rules for more info.

Comment: is this your complete apache config ? are there any <directory/ directives ?
what error do you get (take a look at error log file) when you try to connect from a remote host ?

Comment: can you provide that from _BOTH_ of virtualhosts not just one?

Answer (score 1):

Since a proxypass setup operates entirely in the (virtual) URL-space, you need to grant access to each vhost via a Location directive:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ServerName 192.168.1.1
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, get rid of the NameVirtualHosts if you're not using them, and a ServerName must be a hostname, there is no scheme or port or whatever. Just a hostname.

Comment: The added location directive had no impact on any of the results.  Nor did the NameVirtualHosts (But I suppose thats a win, as the local requets was still successfully routed thru the proxy)

Comment: If there is no Documentroot for these vhosts, access control may not matter. Every vhost needs a DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide:

- curl syntax/output (use verbose)
- logs from apache
- ifconfig output
- cat /etc/hosts
- firewall ruleset
- SELinux enable/disable?

*** UPDATE ***

also `ServerAlias` you should remove `http://` part as that not needed, not to mention that since your `ServerName` is same as `ServerAlias`, `ServerAlias` is just not needed.

Comment: Nor is the entirety of that ServerAlias, since it is identical to the  - already superfluous - `ServerName this.is.my.ip` form.

Comment: ServerName can be IP (it doesn't make any sense but it can) ServerAlias is not needed if ServerName has same thing.

Comment: I did not say it could not be an IP. I said it was superfluous.

Comment: @adaptr, right I'm agreeing with you) I'm just expanding my answer.

Comment: Then why don't you...expand your answer ?

Comment: @adaptr I just updated my answer)